# Storm-kafka: set startOffsetTime to kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime in apache Flux Yaml topology

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am working on a topology using apache flux. Currently, strom fetches messages from beginning but  I want it to fetch only the latest messages from kafka.

I am writing topology in YAML file.

This is how my spoutConfig looks like:

```
  - id: "stringScheme"
    className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.StringScheme"

  - id: "stringMultiScheme"
    className: "org.apache.storm.spout.SchemeAsMultiScheme"
    constructorArgs:
      - ref: "stringScheme"

  - id: "zkHosts"
    className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.ZkHosts"
    constructorArgs:
      - "172.25.33.191:2181"

  - id: "spoutConfig"
    className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.SpoutConfig"
    constructorArgs:
      - ref: "zkHosts"
      - "blockdata"
      - ""
      - "myId"
    properties:
      - name: "scheme"
        ref: "stringMultiScheme"

      - name: "ignoreZkOffsets"
        value: true

      - name: "startOffsetTime"
        ref: "XXXXXXXXX"
```

Now, I am stuck. How do I set startOffsetTime to proper function to get only the latest messages from kafka?

I have tried ref:"LatestTime", but no matter what I put in there, it give me error :

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set long field org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaConfig.startOffsetTime to null value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Flux can handle calling static factory methods.

```
- id: "startingOffsetTime"
  className: "kafka.api.OffsetRequest"
  factory: "LatestTime"
```

and then use it in your SpoutConfig definition like

```
properties:
  - name: "startOffsetTime"
    ref: "startingOffsetTime"
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work. The ability to call static factory methods was merged a while back https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-2796, but it seems to be missing from the documentation. I've raised an issue to update the docs https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-3086.

In case you'd like to see an example of this feature, take a look at https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/flux/flux-core/src/test/resources/configs/config-methods-test.yaml#L38

Comment: I tried the proposed solution but it gives an error :

Exception in thread "main" Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.storm.flux.model.TopologyDef; exception=Cannot create property=components for JavaBean=org.apache.storm.flux.model.TopologyDef@67e2d983; Cannot create property=factory for JavaBean=org.apache.storm.flux.model.BeanDef@4de5031f; Unable to find property 'factory' on class: org.apache.storm.flux.model.BeanDef
 in 'string', line 2, column 1:
    name: "kafka-topology"

Comment: Here's a gist showing a configuration file that will set the startOffsetTime correctly https://gist.github.com/srdo/33fb8e2618fb650114504c90bc20d526. The lines you want are https://gist.github.com/srdo/33fb8e2618fb650114504c90bc20d526#file-kafka_test-yaml-L41 and https://gist.github.com/srdo/33fb8e2618fb650114504c90bc20d526#file-kafka_test-yaml-L72. I've tested it against Storm/Flux 1.2.1. Could you try it out?

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and will let you know.

Comment: I am doing the same thing, please see my gist here https://gist.github.com/obiii/178f699514d4994b7ec1005cd1062bbb

And my storm version is Storm 1.2.1

You can see my gist, I am doing exactly the same thing :/

Comment: I get a very similar error if I try the example against an older version of Flux. Can you verify that you're using Flux 1.2.1?

Comment: THANK YOU SO  MUCHHHHHH. I was stuck at this for a day. You are right. I needed Flux 1.2.1 for this.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: But only one problem remains, it closes connection if there is no data in kafka, it does not wait for data and shows this error : https://ibb.co/fMmQ6T
This is last issue I am facing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171858/discussion-between-obaid-ur-rehman-and-stig-rohde-dossing).